# Can I Share a Home Partition on a Multi Boot USB Drive

Tags: grub2, partitioning, usb, live-usb

I have a pendrive made using mkusb.

It has the standard Persistent setup with ISO9660 OS partition, boot, casper-rw and usbdata partitions.

I would like to add a Full install Ubuntu partition and a /home partition.

I may also add some iso's to boot later.

How can I share the home partition between the various OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sharing home Partition on a Multiple Boot USB

/home and home-rw may share a partition on a bootable USB drive, offering a link between Full and Persistent installs to the same USB. This also allows multiple installs and bootable ISOs to each have a home folder greater than 4GB each.

- Using mkusb, install Ubuntu to a 4GB pendrive as a Live install, (no persistence, important). Use default settings
- Using mkusb, install Ubuntu to a 32GB pendrive as a Persistent install, Use default settings but allow 21GB for persistence.
- Shrink partition 5 to 7GB and add 2 more ext4 partitions.
- Remove casper-rw label from Partition 5.
- Make a copy of 32GB Partition 3 /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
- Plug in both pendrives and boot into the 4GB drive.
- Select Install.
- At "Something else" select the 32GB drive for boot loader.
- Select partition 7, change to ext4, Format and /.
- Select partition 6, change to ext4, Format and /home.
- Select "Install now" and complete installation.
- Open the 32GB pendrive in GParted.
- Change the label of Partition 5 back to casper-rw.
- Change the label of Partition 6 to home-rw.

[image]

- Open the copied grub.cfg and copy any menuentries you want to use.
- Paste the selected menuentries into Partition 7 /etc/grub.d/40_custom/
- Run sudo update-grub from the Full install.
- You may add as many Users as you have OS.
- The same username can share a home folder between installs as long as the flavor of Ubuntu is the same, Ubuntu version may vary.

Comment: +1. Good instructions :-) I have a question: *Are you able to boot this system in both UEFI and BIOS mode?* I did it this way: Install the installed system in BIOS mode and write the bootloader to the root partition of the installed system (*not* to the head of the drive). This will not overwrite the boot system of mkusb. In such a system there is one more step: copy `grub.cfg` from the installed system (after all your steps) to the location in partition #3. But if you are happy with either boot mode (only UEFI or only BIOS), your instructions will work and are easier to maintain.

Comment: Yesterday I got turned around and installed to root of the drive. I had to copy menuentries from a saved original mkusb grub.cfg to /etc/grub.d/40_custom and update-grub. Drive is using grub.cfg from sdc7. I did not format sdc3 in Something else, grub.cfg from sdc3 is not being used. Everything seems to be working fine BIOS and UEFI. Will keep experimenting.